# How can I play a sound when a tkinter button is pushed?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, button, audio, tkinter

I am building a program for Windows PCs that contains a lot of buttons and seems very plain. So I was wondering, can I make it so when you push a button (using tkinter), can I play a sound to liven up the program a bit? Please keep in mind I am learning so please dumb it down a bit.

Answer (score 12):

Assuming your file is a WAV:

```
from tkinter import *
from winsound import *

root = Tk() # create tkinter window

play = lambda: PlaySound('Sound.wav', SND_FILENAME)
button = Button(root, text = 'Play', command = play)

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Assuming your file is a MP3:

```
from Tkinter import *
import mp3play

root = Tk() # create tkinter window

f = mp3play.load('Sound.mp3'); play = lambda: f.play()
button = Button(root, text = 'Play', command = play)

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: does mp3play come in the default python library or do i have to dl it?

Comment: It does not work on my operation system, is the error was raised when I tried to run it in my Linux system

Comment: @RogerAlmengor of course, it is raised, because the **win**sound (and mp3play, too) are only for Windows, they're not cross-platform. To make my app work on more operation systems, I use Pygame.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to consider using [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/) as a cross-platform alternative to `winsound`.

```
import tkinter as tk

from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
sound = mixer.Sound("sound.ogg")

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, command=sound.play).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Refer to the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) for more information.

Comment: Right on.  You don't have to import *all of pygame* for that tho.  There's a good couple megs of graphical functions that'll never get touched.  You could just import that required mixer component, `from pygame import mixer`  then change all your commands from `pygame.mixer.init()` to simply read `mixer.init()`

Comment: @Doyousketch2, thank you for the reply. Indeed, it's unnecessary to import all modules from `pygame` if all we need is `pygame.mixer`. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to link the click of your mouse on the image, with an even handler, then simply define an on_click function:

```
def on_click(event): 
    winsound.Beep('frequency', 'duration')
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) you can find more information about playing sounds in python.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
import os
os.system("play sound.mp3")
```

Comment: did not work at all