# winsound in a tkinter variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, winsound

I have made a hangman game in Tkinter with buttons for each letter, each button is linked to a function that will process the letter and tell me if it is correct or not. How can I make a function a correct sound and an incorrect sound, I do not want to say where I am getting my wav file from, because it will move (it will always be in the same file as my programme).i do not want to download another module and the answers from another question do not work.

i tried this but it did not make a sound:

```
def no():
    lambda: PlaySound('wrong.wav', SND_FILENAME)
def yes():
    lambda: PlaySound('right.wav', SND_FILENAME)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I play a sound when a tkinter button is pushed? - Python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795859/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-tkinter-button-is-pushed-python-3-4)

Comment: You don't need the lambda there. Get rid of the `lambda:` and it should work (provided the rest of your code is correct).

Comment: @Nae the answer there did not work , but i have resolved the issue now, lambda is unnecesary

Comment: @UrielSasieni If you've resolved your issue please provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem unclear what `lambda` does:

> [Python supports the creation of anonymous functions (i.e. functions that are not bound to a name) at runtime, using a construct called "lambda".](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)

In the example you have given you have not created any anonymous function so therefore they are totally unnecessary.  Just remove them and everything should work.

```
def no():
    PlaySound('wrong.wav', SND_FILENAME)
def yes():
    PlaySound('right.wav', SND_FILENAME)
```

Remember however winsound is Windows only (so no cross platform development) and to use these functions you need `from winsound import *`