# Sounds in Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, tkinter

I am making a game in Python using the tkinter library. I want to add background music to the program, and for another sound to work when the button is pressed. What libraries are there for this? And how can this be implemented?

Comment: Use `pygame` could be easy.

Comment: There are plenty of resources. Please do not use the forum as replacement for a search engine. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795859/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-tkinter-button-is-pushed

Comment: You may also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795859/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-tkinter-button-is-pushed/61444109#61444109