# Importing and using mp3s on button press

Tags: python, tkinter, mp3

So I have coded a "copy" of the game 2048 after following a Kite youtube tutorial. I want to add a small mp3 to play anytime you click an arrow key(to move stuff around in the game) but I'm not entirely sure what i'm doing right or wrong here. How do I do this?
I've snipped the important stuff out(import music is a folder for my mp3s)

```
import tkinter as tk
import mp3play
import music
```

The two errors I'm getting are down below, the Tk in Tk() is underlined and the root in left(root...)
when i attempt to run the code like this, it highlights "import mp3play" and says there is a Syntax error. Not sure why, I have in fact installed mp3play via pip installer as well

```
root = Tk()

f = mp3play.load('beep.mp3'); play = lambda: f.play()
button = left(root, text = "Play", command = play)
```

```
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

in between the 2 middle sections is the def for up, down, left, and right but that would just clutter this question

Here is the stackoverflow I've referenced for it, to be honest I dont understand half of it. [How can I play a sound when a tkinter button is pushed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795859/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-a-tkinter-button-is-pushed)

Comment: `Tk()` should be `tk.Tk()`.  Where is `left()` defined?  Should it be `tk.Button()` instead?

Comment: Note that `mp3play` module is not Python 3 compatible.

Comment: Ive added an answer, do let me know

Comment: You said you replaced code, with the new one, but i dont see any fragments of my answer

Comment: forgot to edit that in 1 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this simple example using `winsound` which is easier to handle for small beeps.

```
from tkinter import *
import winsound

root = Tk()

def play():
    winsound.Beep(1000, 100)

b = Button(root,text='Play',command=play)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`winsound.Beep(1000, 100)` takes two positional arguemnts, `1000` is the frequency and `100` is the duration in milliseconds.

Do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: I'm still looking into it, but that mostly worked, I can initialize the game now and play it but it keeps saying "pygame.error: couldn't open beep.wav"
I'm going to edit the post to show the code I have for my buttons. Also was the b, b1, b2 ect their own thing or am i supposed to integrate that into my buttons?

Comment: @Addabhi Try changing the format of the audio using online converters and try again

Comment: I converted to wav from mp3 already but i can try the other supported format

Comment: @Addabhi Do try and update the code with where your using `pygame`

Comment: Also you can directly use your `mp3` files too. The problem with wav or mp3 might be that the the decoding and the frequency is higher than what pygame can handle and hence it cannot open the file.

Comment: So I swapped to OGG as well, and it still doesn't seem to load, it may be the way I have buttons coded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221887/discussion-between-addabhi-and-cool-cloud).