# Why can't I use a background music in Python?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm learning Python by making small games, with Turtle.
I want a background music playing. It's the only sound that doesn't work.
When I add this sound, other sounds don't work also !

Here is what I get :

```
winsound.PlaySound("background.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
RuntimeError: Failed to play sound
```

My code:

```
while True:
winsound.PlaySound("background.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)

wn.update()

# Move the ball
ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)
```

Comment: Either way you don't want to start this sound on every update. I.e. you better move `PlaySound` out of the loop

Comment: Ya might have better luck with [pygame's mixer command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61444109/3342050)

Answer (score 0):

You should play the sound in another thread so that the code will be executing at the same time.

```
import time
import winsound
from threading import Thread

def play_sound():
   winsound.PlaySound("./background.wav", winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC)

while True:
   thread = Thread(target=play_sound)
   thread.start()
   print ('hello')
   time.sleep(2)
```

I don't have experience with this module but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just `import playsound` get the audio file you need and run it.

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('audio.mp3') # The audio file you want to play.
```